# Python27: Subclassing a class by using type

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following class

```
class Sample(object):
    def __init__(self, argument, argument2, argument3):
        self.value = argument
        self.value2 = argument2
        self.value3 = argument3
```

and I want to create a subclass of this by using **type** however I am not sure on how to populate the arguments to the **__ init __** method.

I also have this custom **__ init __** method which populates the object:

```
def setup(self, arg, arg2, arg3):
    self.value = "good"
    self.value2 = "day"
    self.value3 = "sir"

myclass = type("TestSample", (Sample,), dict(__init__=setup))
```

however when I perform:

```
myclass()
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: setup() takes exactly 4 arguments (1 given)
```

Is there a way to pre-stuff these values in without having to provide them at object instatiation?

Comment: You're probably looking for default arguments, written as `def f(x=1, y=2, ...): (...)`. Be advised however that those are mutable, e.g. if you use a container type (list, dict, set etc) as a default argument and add a value to it, it will still have that value on the next call.

Comment: oh! so if I provide default arguments, then they wont take into effect due to the altered __init__ method? Ill give that a go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subclass is working fine, but you gave it their own `__init__` method that still takes *four positional arguments*. One of those is `self`, but you still need to provide the other 3 when creating the object:

```
myclass('some', 'argument', 'values')
```

Your function is *ignoring* those arguments otherwise, so perhaps you meant to not include them in the function signature? You don't have to match the parent class here:

```
def setup(self):
    self.value = "good"
    self.value2 = "day"
    self.value3 = "sir"

myclass = type("TestSample", (Sample,), dict(__init__=setup))
```

Instead of setting the attributes directly, you could delegate that to the parent class still:

```
def setup(self):
    Sample.__init__(self, 'good', 'day', 'sir')

myclass = type("TestSample", (Sample,), dict(__init__=setup))
```

If you wanted these to be *defaults* that you can override, use keyword arguments:

```
def setup(self, argument='good', argument2='day', argument3='sir'):
    Sample.__init__(self, argument, argument2, argument3)

myclass = type("TestSample", (Sample,), dict(__init__=setup))
```

Now you can either omit the arguments, or provide different values for them:

```
c1 = myclass()
c2 = myclass(argument2='weekend')
```

Comment: Why if I do a partial on setup does it not work ? i.e. dict(__init__=partial(setup, argument="good", argument2="day", argument3="sir")) whilst removing the default arguments. Isn't that equivalent to the first and second example of setup?

Comment: @Har: `functools.partial()` objects do not implement the descriptor protocol and thus cannot be used as methods. Python 3.4 adds a [`partialmethod` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partialmethod) that *does*.

Comment: wow thanks. I havnt come across the descriptor protocol before, Ill look into it

Comment: @Har: there is a somewhat [technical HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) on the subject.